# Extracting Event Variable Data for AWS Lambda Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, event-handling

I have an AWS Lambda function that sends an email through SNS, with a Node.js 10.x runtime.  The event object contains a variable called client_id that corresponds to a Raspberry Pi device id in IoT Core service.  I see the following in the Cloudwatch logs for the Lambda function:

console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

2020-09-05T00:21:35.587Z    229b8110-852a-4abe-8b9c-4d06a121d63f    INFO    EVENT:
{
"client_id": "RaspberryPi001"
}

I need to extract the client_id from the event and include it in the Message text for the email, in order to specify which device is issuing an email alert. How do I extract the client_id and include it in the email Message text?

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
// Create publish parameters
var params = {

            Message: `The air quality in your building has triggered a High Risk Alert.`,
            Subject: `Air Quality - High Risk Alert`,
            TopicArn: `arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xyz`,
        };

// Create promise and SNS service object
var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();

// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states

publishTextPromise.then(
  function(data) {
    console.log("Message: " + params.Message);
    console.log("Sent to the topic: " + params.TopicArn);
    console.log("MessageID is " + data.MessageId);
    console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
  });
  
  const data = await publishTextPromise;
  return data;

};
```

Thanks!

Comment: From the debug log you provided, it looks like the client ID is available at `event.client_id`. One question: what is actually triggering the Lambda function?

Comment: The Lambda function is triggered by an IoT Events Detector Model.  When a set of conditions are met on the Input, the Lambda is triggered with a custom payload including the client_id.

Comment: OK thanks. I ask because it's a little unusual to see event data attached to the root of the event object directly, rather than under it e.g. in an `event.Records[]` record. From a quick glance at the [IoT events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-iotevents.html) doc, I'd expect it to be under `event.payload`, for example.

Comment: it was added as a custom JSON payload '{\"client_id\": \"${$input.SBSInput.ClientId}\"}'